# Android Animation to move an image button in circle on touch

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a image view (example: a world map) on top of which I have few location points. Location points are image buttons with just a square image and a text written below the square. I have a custom relative layout that handles touch to rotate the globe in a circular fashion.

Now, how to keep the text of the image button to remain parallel to x-axis or in other words, parallel to the width of the screen when I touch and rotate the globe? The image button rotates at an angle on touch and rotate of the globe.

Could anyone provide with the animation required to keep the image button text always parallel to the x-axis on touch and rotation of the background globe? A pointer I had was to move the image button in a small circular fashion (in a invisible circular path) so that the text remains always parallel to the width of the screen. A small drawback with this approach is that the button will move slightly in a circular fashion from its original point of location.

Can anyone help with the Android animation to move the image button on a small circular path on top of a image view?

My layout is as below
`

```
<com.mycompany.view.RotateRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/test_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/test_margin_top"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_globe"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/test_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/test_layout_height" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/test_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/test_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/test_layout_height">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/test_button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/test_button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/test_button1"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.mycompany.view.RotateRelativeLayout>
```

`

And the custom relative layout which I am using to touch and rotate the globe is as follows

`

```
public class RotateRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    private float mCenterX, mCenterY;
    private float direction = 0;
    private float sX, sY;
    private float startDirection = 0;

    public RotateRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private double angleBetween2Lines(float centerX, float centerY, float x1,
                                      float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        double angle1 = Math.atan2(y1 - centerY, x1 - centerX);
        double angle2 = Math.atan2(y2 - centerY, x2 - centerX);
        return angle1 - angle2;
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mCenterX = this.getWidth() / 2;
        mCenterY = this.getHeight() / 2;
        sX = x;
        sY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        // this calculates the angle the image rotate
        float angle = (float) angleBetween2Lines(mCenterX, mCenterY, sX, sY, x, y);
        direction = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle) * -1 + startDirection;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        setRotation(direction);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // record the start position of finger
                touchStart(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // update image angle
                touchMove(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                startDirection = direction;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

`

So, essentially my relative layout should respond to touch events and animate the image button. I have attempted here but this doesn't work
`

```
final RotateRelativeLayout rotateRelativeLayout = (RotateRelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.test_relative_layout);
        rotateRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private float mCenterX = rotateRelativeLayout.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            private float mCenterY = rotateRelativeLayout.getHeight() / 2.0f;

            private void animate(View view, double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long duration) {
                final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                rotate.setDuration(duration);
                rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
                rotate.setFillAfter(true);
                rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                rotate.setRepeatCount(1);
                view.startAnimation(rotate);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                float x = motionEvent.getX();
                float y = motionEvent.getY();
                final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.test_button1);

                double angle1 = 0, angle2 = 0;

                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        angle1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y - mCenterY, x - mCenterX));
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        angle2 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y - mCenterY, x - mCenterX));
                        animate(imageButton, -angle1, -(angle2-angle1), 0);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

`

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep text position fix?

Comment: May be this ferris wheel example could help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15755020/320111

Comment: @RIT: Yes, I mean to keep the text parallel to x-axis or the width of the screen. At this time, when I touch and rotate the outer globe, the image button text also moves at an angle, which I need to avoid

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @RIT: I have updated my question with the relevant part of layout and custom relative layout code

Comment: @RIT or anyone reading this post: Could anybody help with pointers on how to animate the image button with its text to remain parallel to the x-axis when the custom relative layout is touched and rotated?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: The ferris wheel does rotation. I want the image button to translate in a curved fashion on touch of the outer relative layout (test_relative_layout)

Comment: @elizabetht, In my example, the ferris wheel rotates, but the chairs stay parallel to the ground as they rotate, thus each chair are doing their own curve. This effect was created by having each chair rotating on its own axis while the ferris wheel (the container layout) rotated in the opposite direction on its own axis as well. It's the combination of the two on each chair that creates the resulting curving effect. You should really try the example to see what I'm talking about. It works. The touch part, that's not what you want, but that part can easily be changed.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Even in my example, I have animated the frame layout to rotate in a direction and image button to animate in the exact opposite direction to make the image button text remain parallel to the horizontal axis. THis is similar to what you have in ferris wheel - rotate the container in a given direction and rotate the chairs in opposite direction. Now, the problem I have is to get the same behavior of image button to remain parallel to horizontal axis on touching and rotating the relative layout (which is the outer container of the frame layout). Hope I making my point clear

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Is there a touch part in your code? I do not see it in the example?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: To make the question clear, how to retain the button to remain parallel to horizontal axis on touch and rotate of the outer container? What animation should I apply?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Could you help with any pointers? I have been stuck with this for a couple of days now.